C++ map: How do I get the key that was used to add an element into a std::map?
I'm creating a std::map using keys that contain e.g. doubles as identifiers. However, I need the keys to have some leeway, i.e. tolerance, to identify a key as "the same".
I've successfully managed to implement that by defining the operators < and == myself.
I'm now in the following situation: Say I add an element to my map using some key a. I can now retrieve the values stored with that key using some key b, whose identifying double is slightly off from a's. That's all as intended. However, what I want now is to compare the difference between the keys a and b. To do so, I'm looking for a way to retrieve a from the map.
Is there any way of doing so without iterating over the entire map to find the first element that passes a == b ?
Here's example code of what I'm trying to do:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class myKey {

public:
  myKey(double x, double tolerance=0.5);
  double getX() const;
  bool operator<(const myKey& rhs) const;
  bool operator==(const myKey& rhs) const;

private:

  double _x;
  double _tolerance;

};

myKey::myKey(double x, double tolerance){
  _x = x;
  _tolerance = tolerance;
}

double myKey::getX() const {
  return _x;
}

bool myKey::operator<(const myKey& rhs) const {
  return (rhs._x - _x) > _tolerance;
}

bool myKey::operator==(const myKey& rhs) const {
  return std::abs(_x - rhs._x) < _tolerance;
}


// --------------------------------------------------

int main() {

  std::map<myKey, double> myMap;

  // create a key and assign it a value in the map
  myKey a = myKey(1.234, 0.5);
  double aval = 3.14159;
  myMap[a] = aval;

  double value_of_a_in_map = myMap[a];
  std::cout << "Checking myMap[a]: ";
  std::cout << "same value? " <<
    (aval == value_of_a_in_map) << std::endl;

  // Get a new key that should pass a == b
  // since it's within the tolerance of 0.5
  myKey b = myKey(1.345, 0.5);
  std::cout << "a == b? " << (a == b) << std::endl;

  // retrieve value of `a` from map using `b`
  double value_of_a_in_map_using_b = myMap[b];

  std::cout << "Checking myMap[b]: ";
  std::cout << "same value? " <<
    (aval == value_of_a_in_map_using_b) << std::endl;

  // How do I get original value(s) of `myKey a` from the map?
  // Can I do it without iterating over the entire map?

  // This works
  for (auto entry: myMap){
    myKey mapKey = entry.first;
    if (mapKey == b) {
      std::cout << "Found a ! x= " << mapKey.getX() << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

EDIT:
Adding code snippet of my solution following HolyBlackCat's answer:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cassert>

class myIDKey {
public:
  myIDKey(double x);
  myIDKey(){};
  double getX() const;

private:
  double _x;
};



myIDKey::myIDKey(double x){
  _x = x;
}

double myIDKey::getX() const {
  return _x;
}


bool operator<(const myIDKey& lhs, const myIDKey& rhs) {
  return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
}

bool operator==(const myIDKey& lhs, const myIDKey& rhs) {
  return lhs.getX() == rhs.getX();
}


class mySearchKey : public myIDKey {
public:
  mySearchKey(double x, double tolerance = 0.5);
  mySearchKey(){};
  double getTolerance() const;

private:
  double _tolerance;
};



mySearchKey::mySearchKey(double x, double tolerance): myIDKey::myIDKey(x) {
  _tolerance = tolerance;
}

double mySearchKey::getTolerance() const {
  return _tolerance;
}

bool operator<(const mySearchKey& lhs, const mySearchKey& rhs) {
  return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX();
}

bool operator==(const mySearchKey& lhs, const mySearchKey& rhs) {
  return lhs.getX() == rhs.getX();
}


bool operator<(const mySearchKey& lhs, const myIDKey& rhs) {
  return (lhs.getX() - rhs.getX()) < -lhs.getTolerance();
}

bool operator==(const mySearchKey& lhs, const myIDKey& rhs) {
  return std::abs(rhs.getX() - lhs.getX()) < lhs.getTolerance();
}


bool operator<(const myIDKey& lhs, const mySearchKey& rhs) {
  return (lhs.getX() - rhs.getX()) < -rhs.getTolerance();
}

bool operator==(const myIDKey& lhs, const mySearchKey& rhs) {
  return std::abs(rhs.getX() - lhs.getX()) < rhs.getTolerance();
}





// --------------------------------------------------

int main() {

  // tell the map to use std::less<> as comparator instead
  // of std::less<key>. std::less<> invokes the `<` operator.
  // We want that to be able to use our bespoke `<` operator
  // for different search and ID keys.
  std::map<myIDKey, double, std::less<>> myMap;

  myIDKey keyA(1.);
  myMap[keyA] = 1.;

  myIDKey keyB(2.);
  myMap[keyB] = 2.;


  mySearchKey searchKeyA = mySearchKey(1., 0.5);
  mySearchKey searchKeyA2 = mySearchKey(1.2, 0.5);


  auto search1 = myMap.find(searchKeyA);
  if (search1 != myMap.end()) {
    assert(search1->first.getX() == keyA.getX());
    std::cout << "Search 1 successful" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Search 1 failed" << std::endl;
  }

  auto search2 = myMap.find(searchKeyA2);
  if (search2 != myMap.end()) {
    assert(search2->first.getX() == keyA.getX());
    assert(search2->first.getX() != searchKeyA2.getX());
    std::cout << "Search 2 successful" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Search 2 failed" << std::endl;
  }


  std::cout << "Done." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


Presume you need to write your own hash for it. But I'll suggest use int with a designated precision. Just override < and == doesn't work since you might have overlap values. The key must have a definite value when it's inserted. Eg: truncate to a specified limit. My gut feeling is that you're looking for a lookup/ mapping table.

Maybe you can explain us first what problem you are trying to solve with this "solution". I have the feeling a map is just not the right datastructure to use

Using floating point values as map keys is fraught with potential issues, see this post

If your map keys are not exact values but have a tolerance to them, then there is simply no way to retrieve the exact key value used to add an element. Rethink your design.

I suggest you create your own mapping structure to hold the data you need. Using std::map will simply not work. By using a range you break strict weak ordering required by any standard ordering function.

@PepijnKramer I've reduced what I'm doing to a minimal working example to showcase the problem I'm facing. What I'm actually trying to do is maintain a database of a particle event history in my simulation. Due to additional circumstances, it is not possible to ID particles by a single unique integer ID, but their coordinates need to be taken into account as well. In combination with their ID, it allows for a (much) bigger comparison tolerance than double precision allows for, so the comparisons there should be safe. I do however need to make sure the particles haven't moved too much from -

@PepijnKramer - the position stored in their key used as the identifier in the map. For that, I face the problem above: I need to access the key used in the map.

std::map is designed to make looking up values by key easy and efficient. It doesn't provide anything other than brute force to look up the keys themselves.

This seems to be an XY problem. I guess you need to put more effort on abstraction of your problem. std::map is just a memoized implementation of a mathematical mapping with fast lookups on domain.

@user4581301 Yes it does. std::map::find, std::map::lower_bound, and std::map_upper_bound can tell you the exact key efficiently.

I'll take that one.  Forgot that because the keys are ordered brute-force look up's not required.

What you're doing is not legal in the first place. The map comparator must implement strict weak ordering, and yours doesn't because e.g. your equivalence (that is, !(a < b) && !(b < a)) is not transitive: 0 ≡ 0.4 and 0.4 ≡ 0.8, but 0 ≢ 0.8.
The correct way of doing this is;

Don't store the tolerance in the key, make <,== return the exact result.
Add a second key type that does store tolerance, and can be compared with the first type (either directly or via a comparator, see below).
Specify a transparent comparator for your map: either std::less<> (with no argument type, aka std::less<void>) (if you overloaded < to compare the two different key types), or your own that supports both types.
Use the second key type to search in the map, either with .find() or with .equal_range().

Then you can examine .first in the returned iterators to see the original key.

Also, don't use NaN values as keys, i.e., filter the input carefully.

@PeteBecker Yep, or compare using std::weak_order() or std::strong_order() to handle nans.

I hadn't thought of that. My un-nuanced view on NaNs is that they're a sign of trouble, and should be eliminated at the earliest opportunity. But there are legitimate reasons for keeping them around.

map requires a Strict Weak Ordering. If you try to add a "tolarance" like this, that is not a strict weak ordering, and as a result, the map will "randomly" make new nodes when they should have been merged, and it will "randomly" merge nodes that it should not have, and it will randomly run the wrong code, erasing your Documents folder. Whoopsie. Don't do that.
However, not all hope is lost! The simplest solution is to make a fuzzy_map class, which contains a std::multi_map<mostly_unique_key, data> member. Your class would then have a method that linearly iterates over the nodes with that mostly_unique_key, and checks for nodes within your tolarance, and either returns that data, or creates new data, or whatever you want to happen. Note that since tolarance is not transitive, there's good odds you'll accidentally write code that merge nodes that shouldn't have merged, or fail to merge nodes that should have, so you have to think really hard about exactly what you need.
If you don't have any sort of non-fuzzy mostly_unique_key, then this is still solvable. You make your class contain a std::map<double, data>, and then your method would linearly iterate from map.lower_bound(x-tolarance) to map.upper_bound(x+tolarance), and then again figure out the merging logic yourself.
Circling back to the actual question you asked, std::map::lower_bound, std::map::upper_bound, and std::map::find all return iterators to std::pair<key, value>, allowing you to examine the original key used in the insert. You can't modify the key directly, but you can read it, and then remove/reinsert the whole node if needed.

You need to define a comparison for the keys that take into account a tolerance, which you used to define the map type:
constexpr auto tol = 0.5;

// comparision of keys
struct dbl_comp_with_tol
{
    bool operator()(double v1, double v2) const { return v1 - v2 < -tol; };
};

// map double(with tol) -> std::string
std::map<double, std::string, dbl_comp_with_tol> the_map;

Then when you find an element in the map for a given key, you can compare the keys from the map with the one you used to find the element:
    // look for a value associated with b, and report distance to its key:
    auto i_b = the_map.find(b);
    if (i_b != the_map.end())
    {
        std::cout << "I found a value for " << b << " set against " << i_b->first << ": " << i_b->second << ".\n"
            << "The difference between the keys was " << (i_b->first - b) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "I didn't find a value for " << b << std::endl;
    }

All in one example: https://godbolt.org/z/z3ca6ddcP
